# unit tests in googletest executable not picked up by vstest

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I have a (native C++) executable (test_descriptions.exe) that contains some googletests (1.7). Just running the executable works fine and it nicely goes through the tests. Now I would like to run these tests automatically in TFS, using `vstest`.

Unfortunately, applying `vstest` on my executable gives the following error:

```
C:\project>"C:\Program Files BLABLA \vstest.console.exe" test_descriptions.exe /platform:x64

Warning: Using Isolation mode to run tests as required by effective Platform:X64 and .Net Framework:Framework45 settings for test run. Use the /inIsolation parameter to suppress this warning.
Warning: No test is available in test_descriptions.exe. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

Any idea? Would there be better ways of running these tests in TFS (I've considered just building the RUN_TESTS project and letting cmake's ctest do the work)

EDIT: I've also tried adding `/UseVsixEntensions:true`, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the reference to Google Test Adapter was missing. `/UseVxisEntensions:true` is deprecated, one should now use `\TestAdapterPath:` to set the location of Google Test Adapters' DLLs